# The Swing window builder in eclipse defining variables in constructor

Tags: java, swing

What happens is that when I use swing window builder it creates the variables in constructor not in class itself. So is there any way I can modify it to create the variables in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the highlighted button to move the field.

[image]

Or even right click on the widget and `Convert local to field`.

[image]

See also this at the [WindowBuilder User Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Findex.html).